# How to tell kysely key-gen to use primitive data types when mapping db tables

Tags: typescript, kysely

I am using kysely-codegen to generate all the models from the database, but I am seeing a weird behavior in there, it is adding a `Generated` type on any field, why is not generating a `number` or `boolean` only?

Does anybody know if it is possible to prevent this?

```
export interface MyTable {
  id: Generated<Numeric>
  otherColumn: Generated<boolean>
```